# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I am trying to save my data against my userid but I am getting this error.

**My code is:**

```
        \App\Keys::create([
         $user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user(),
        'user_id' => $user,
        'accessTokenKey' => $accessTokenKey,
        'accessTokenSecret' => $accessTokenSecret
    ]);
    return 'You have successfully granted';
```

I am getting error user_id does not have a default value and when I passed Auth::user()->id it says trying to get properties of non-object id.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you do not have an authenticated user1

Comment: `Auth::user()->id` only gave you an id if any user logged in!

Comment: My user is logged in but it is not saving my user_id.

Comment: what should i do in this problem

Comment: Why are you assigning the user within the create method?

Comment: is there any suitable method for this @linkoahref

Comment: I meant why `$user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user()` statement within the create method. Can't you declare user outside the create method and use `'user_id' => ($user) ? $user->id : 0`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you do not have any authenticated user

```
if(Auth::check()){
        \App\Keys::create([
          $user = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::user(),
          'user_id' => Auth::id(),
          'accessTokenKey' => $accessTokenKey,
          'accessTokenSecret' => $accessTokenSecret
      ]);
}else{
    //logged in the user or
    return 'User is not logged in ';
}
```

Comment: @syed1234  is the user_id required for creating ?

Comment: yes it is required because i want to save my keys against user_id

Comment: so we need a logged in user other wise don't don't create the  key

Comment: that exactly i want save my keys against my logged in user

Comment: Then first login that user and then create this part! You can easily get current user after their login!

Comment: @syed1234 ok let me modify the answer

Comment: shows user is not logged in, even user is logged in.. that horrible :(

Comment: wihat if i want to pass token of logged in user when i logged in i am having  a token? how to pass token ?